# Computational cost of math operations in GLSL

Tags: glsl

I'm writing a GPGPU program using GLSL shaders and am trying to come up with a few optimizations for an N-body collision detection algorithm. One is performing a 'quick' check to determine whether two objects are even in the same ballpark. The idea is to quickly disqualify lots of possibilities so that I only have to perform a more accurate collision test on a handful of objects. If the quick check decides there's a chance they might collide, the accurate check is performed.

The objects are circles (or spheres). I know the position of their center and their radius. The quick check will see if their square (or cube) bounding boxes overlap:

```
//make sure A is to the right of and above B
//code for that

if(A_minX > B_maxX) return false;   //they definitely don't collide
if(A_minY > B_maxY) return false;   //they definitely don't collide

if(length(A_position - B_position) <= A_radius + B_radius){
    //they definitely do collide
    return true;
}
```

My question is whether the overhead of performing this quick check (making sure that A and B are in the right order, then checking whether their bounding boxes overlap) is going to be faster than calling `length()` and comparing that against their combined radii.

It'd be useful to know the relative computational cost of various math operations in GLSL, but I'm not quite sure how to discover them empirically or whether this information is already posted somewhere.

Comment: I'd imagine it very much depends on the state of your world. If it's very sparse, with many object pairs hitting the disqualification conditions, then yes: It should be quicker. If many object pairs are requiring the more accurate check, then all the disqualification conditions are doing is adding extra computational work.

Comment: Any idea how much faster? There's a wikipedia article describing the complexity of various operations, but it's very general-purpose: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations I don't know which specific algorithms are used in GLSL. I assume that calculating a square root is expensive, but there seems to be an approximation algorithm that's pretty fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we're on the topic of costs, you don't need two branches here. You can test the results of a component-wise test instead. So, this could be collapsed into a single test using `any (greaterThan (A_min, B_max))`. A good compiler will probably figure this out, but it helps if you consider data parallelism yourself.

Costs are all relative. 15 years ago the arithmetic work necessary to do what `length (...)` does was such that you could do a cubemap texture lookup in less time - on newer hardware you'd be insane to do that because compute is quicker than memory.

To put this all into perspective, thread divergence can be more of a bottleneck than instruction or memory throughput. That is, if two of your shader invocations running in parallel take separate paths through the shader, you may introduce unnecessary performance penalties. The underlying hardware architecture means that things that were once a safe bet for optimization may not be in the future and might even cause your optimization attempt to hurt performance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on thread divergence. Compilers and Parallel Processing are topics I never got around to in school. So probably the best way to optimize in my case is to try this 'optimized' way, then try a version that calls `length()` every time, and see which one runs faster?

Comment: @Justin: Those aren't topics covered in most undergraduate programs, as far as I know so that is understandable. Divergence especially, most discussion of parallel execution will probably be limited to data hazards and synchronization unless you study GPUs specifically. Yes, you could probably microbenchmark this (run the test thousands of times until there is a measurable difference) to get some idea of cost, but intuitively I do not think there will be that much if any difference. The way I see it, branching is more expensive than `length (...)` in this case.

Comment: @Justin: But if you had a situation where you could work out a branch condition that inherently had better than 50/50 odds of succeeding, it could be a win. Like if 90% of your data set fails some test, that's a really good opportunity to use branching to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using square roots (which are implicitly needed for the `length()` function) by comparing the squares of the values.

The test could then look like this:

```
vec3 vDiff = A_position - B_position;
float radSum = A_radius + B_radius;
if (dot(vDiff, vDiff) < radSum * radSum) {
    return true;
}
```

This reduces it back to a single test, but still uses only simple and efficient operations.

Comment: Now there's a clever optimization. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SIMD 'if' operations are expensive since a bunch of ALU's always execute the same command. What happens in practice is that all branches are executed, but some of the ALUs ignore the result (where the 'if' fails).

Therefor branching is far more costly then arithmetic operations. (BTW, this is also true for CPUs with long pipeline - like Intel,AMD, ARM and such)

In your case it is possible to replace all branches by logic operations - which would be much faster, and also remove some of the tests.

Therefore it is likely that

```
return length(A_position - B_position) <= A_radius + B_radius ;
```

Will actually be much faster, without the two additional 'if' statements.

And in your case the sqrt can also be saved:

```
float length2(vec3 a) {
    return dot(a,a)
}

float r = A_radius + B_radius;
return length2(A_position - B_position) <= r*r ;
```